# Equality of two convergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ be absolutely convergent. Let $b_k = (a_0 + 2*a_1 + 2^2*a_2 .... + 2^k*a_k)*2^{-(k+1)}$
Show that $b_k$ is absolutely convergent and that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$

I'm working my way through it to prove $b_k$ is absolutely convergent. I'm not 100 percent there yet but I have an intuition. Let's assume $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$ is absolutely convergent. How can I show they are equal? I see a bijection from $a_n$ to $b_k$ inside the brackets but other than that I don't see a way.

Any help is appreciated at this point
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok I thought I could handle the absolutely convergent part on my own but every criteria fails. It always leads to 1. Could anyone give me a hint on that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Note that $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}2^{-(l+1)}\right)$$

See: [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)

---

Here's way to prove your question using the hint I gave above.

Let $c_l := 2^{-(l+1)}$, then $$b_k = a_0 \cdot 2^{-(k+1)} + a_1 \cdot 2^{-k} + a_2 \cdot 2^{-(k-1)}+ \cdots + a_k \cdot 2^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^ka_n2^{-(k+1-n)}=\sum_{n=0}^ka_nc_{k-n}$$
Hence, we note that this is precisely a cauchy product, giving us
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}2^{-(l+1)}\right)$$
Now, notice that the second term of the product on the right hand side is a geometric series with $r = 1/2 < 1$, hence it converges. We get,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$$

And now, for absolute convergence
$$b_k = \sum_{n=0}^ka_nc_{k-n} \implies |b_k| = \left|\sum_{n=0}^ka_nc_{k-n}\right| \leq \sum_{n=0}^k|a_n||c_{k-n}| \\ \implies \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}|b_k| \leq \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}2^{-(l+1)}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|$$

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely, by comparison test, so does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k$

Answer (score 0):

Collect "similar" terms:
$$
\sum_0^N b_n = \sum_{n=0}^N \sum_{j=0}^n a_j\cdot 2^{-n-1+j} = \sum_{j=0}^N a_j \cdot 2^{j-1} \sum_{n=j}^N 2^{-n}= \sum_{j=0}^N a_j \cdot 2^{j-1} \cdot 2^{-N}(2^{N-j+1}-1) = \sum_0^N a_j (1-2^{j-N-1}) = \sum_0^N a_j - \frac {a_0 + 2a_1 + 2^2 a_2 + \cdots + 2^N a_N}{2^{N+1}} =: A_N - E_N. 
$$
Since $A_N =\sum_0^N a_j$ converges, and by Cesaro--Stolz theorem
$$
\lim E_n = \lim \frac { \sum_0^N 2^j a_j} {2^{N+1}} = \lim \frac {2^N a_N} { 2^{N+1} -2^N} = \lim a_N = 0 
$$
where the last $=$ holds because $\sum a_n$ converges, we have
$$
\sum_0^\infty b_n = \lim (A_n - E_n) = \sum_0^\infty a_n -0 = \sum_0^\infty a_n
$$
as desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me where the -2^N in $\lim E_n = \lim \frac { \sum_0^N 2^j a_j} {2^{N+1}} = \lim \frac {2^N a_N} { 2^{N+1} -2^N} = \lim a_N = 0 $ comes from?

Comment: @the_asdf_word See [Stolz--Cesaro](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem).

Comment: okay but then why is there no additional term in numerator?

Comment: Because applying C-S theorem and the numerator is $(\sum_0^N- \sum_0^{N-1}) a_j 2^j = a_N 2^N$.